# Long string remains unchanged, can python-black convert them into multine

Tags: python, pre-commit, python-black

Before:

```
value = "aldkfdskdksfjdskfj dslkfj sdkl dklsfj dsklfj sdklfjdsklfjdskl fjdskl jdsklf jdsklfj dsklfj dsklfj dsklfj dsklfj dsklfj dsklfj dkl"
```

After running `black --line-length 80 file.py`: (long string remains unchanged)

```
value = "aldkfdskdksfjdskfj dslkfj sdkl dklsfj dsklfj sdklfjdsklfjdskl fjdskl jdsklf jdsklfj dsklfj dsklfj dsklfj dsklfj dsklfj dsklfj dkl"
```

---

**Expected behavior (something close to this):**

```
value = """aldkfdskdksfjdskfj dslkfj sdkl dklsfj dsklfj
        sdklfjdsklfjdskl fjdskl jdsklf jdsklfj dsklfj
        dsklfj dsklfj dsklfj dsklfj dsklfj dkl"""
```

or

```
value = "aldkfdskdksfjdskfj dslkfj sdkl dklsfj dsklfj" \
        "sdklfjdsklfjdskl fjdskl jdsklf jdsklfj dsklfj" \
        "dsklfj dsklfj dsklfj dsklfj dsklfj dkl"
```

[Q] Long string remains unchanged, can `python-black` convert them into multine? If not, is there any other tool to accomplish it?

Comment: I suggest you raise an issue on black github

Comment: @Chris_Rands Done (https://github.com/psf/black/issues/1528). Since it is a global issue I think it may be useful to solve or have a documentation for this. Should I delete my question here?

Comment: @Chris_Rands Done (https://github.com/psf/black/issues/1528) answered: `Black already does wrap long string literals due to #1132(https://github.com/psf/black/pull/1132). We haven't released a new version yet though, so it only lives in the master branch of this repo.`. Should I delete my question?

Comment: You could self-answer the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the following opened github [issue](https://github.com/psf/black/issues/1528#issuecomment-652458027):

> Black already does wrap long string literals due to #1132. We
> haven't released a new version yet though, so it only lives in the
> master branch of this repo.
>
> ````
> (black) richard-26@ubuntu-laptop:~/programming/black$ black test.py -l
> 80 --color --diff
> --- test.py   2020-07-01 14:36:24.700946 +0000
> +++ test.py   2020-07-01 14:36:38.436792 +0000 @@ -1 +1,4 @@
> -value = "aldkfdskdksfjdskfj dslkfj sdkl dklsfj dsklfj sdklfjdsklfjdskl fjdskl jdsklf jdsklfj dsklfj dsklfj dsklfj dsklfj dsklfj dsklfj dkl"
>
> +value = (
> +    "aldkfdskdksfjdskfj dslkfj sdkl dklsfj dsklfj sdklfjdsklfjdskl fjdskl"
> +    " jdsklf jdsklfj dsklfj dsklfj dsklfj dsklfj dsklfj dsklfj dkl"
> +) 
> would reformat test.py 
> All done! ✨  ✨ 
> 1 file would be reformatted. ```
> ````